# How do I change sender address for mpack command?

Tags: email

It seems that Sender's name/email is stored in configuration files somewhere.

How do I change sender's email for `mpack`?

Comment: Please give more details on your specific problem. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @xhienne i have 100+ shell scripts using mpack. after migration all of them are using old sender's email. I need centralized way to change "from" email without the need to modify each script.

Comment: What is your MTA?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro sendmail

Answer (score 1):

mpack uses what is known as the sendmail (compatible API) to work.

Non-root users cannot change the From address of messages; only root is allowed to do that.

Explicit configurations server wide on your MTA of choice (ssmtp, sendmail, postfix) are also able to do that.

With sendmail you may change the from globally following these instructions from http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/change-sender-address-of-outgoing-emails-in-sendmail-571828/

> With sendmail, you can change both the domain and username on a
>   case-by-case basis using the genericstable feature:
>
> 1) Add these statements to your /etc/mail/sendmail.mc file to activate
>   the feature:
>
> ```
> FEATURE(`genericstable',`hash -o /etc/mail/genericstable.db')dnl
> GENERICS_DOMAIN_FILE(`/etc/mail/generics-domains')dnl
> ```
>
> 2) Create a /etc/mail/generics-domains file that is just a list of all
>   the domains that should be inspected. Make sure the file includes your
>   server's canonical domain name, which you can obtain using the
>   command:
>
> ```
> sendmail -bt -d0.1 </dev/null
> ```
>
> Here is a sample /etc/mail/generics-domains file:
>
> ```
> my-site.com another-site.com bigboy.my-site.com
> ```
>
> 3) Create your /etc/mail/genericstable file. First sendmail searches
>   the /etc/mail/generics-domains file for a list of domains to reverse
>   map. It then looks at the /etc/mail/genericstable file for an
>   individual email address from a matching domain. The format of the
>   file is
>
> ```
> linux-username username@new-domain.com
> ```
>
> Here is an example:
>
> ```
> alert security-alert@my-site.com peter urgent-message@my-site.com
> apache mailer@my-site.com
> ```